# Inverse level calculate formula

Tags: math, google-sheets-formula

I have the following level calculate formula:

```
x=10-10(0.974^y)

x = level
y = experience points
10 = the max level
0.974 = the fixed value
```

If I input experience points, it calculates a level, which i round up.

example:
7=10-10*(0.974^45)

**My problem**

Now I like to inverse the formulie, where I can calculate the fixed value when 300 xp is needed to get to level 10. I don't know where to start....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `log` to inverse your exponential function:

```
y = log(-(x-10)/10)/log(0.974)
```

It can be done by two rules in logarithm: 1. `log(a^y) = y log(a)` (if `a > 0`) 2. `log(a)/log(b) = log_b(a)`. The latter shows you can choose any base for the `log` in the proposed inverse formula. Hence, you can use `LOG` function in google sheet to write the formula.

Notice that, based on your formula, `x` should be less than 10 for `y > 0`.

As `x` cannot be exactly `10` (inside the `log` goes to infinity), hence, you can see `9.999` for `x` and get a value of `y` which is about `350`.

Comment: @Wow, that's quick!! I'm afraid i'm a little bit of a noob, i don't get your answer. I'm trying to calculate which fixed number I need to get level 10 at 300xp.

Comment: sorry, ik had to do some homework. I get most of what you are saying now! I found my solution =sum(a^(1/b))